# Export of 3D models with animation to .dae format for use in Augmented Faces on iOS with ARCore?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, arcore

The model created in 3dsMax with parametric animation (rotation around the axis) was exported to the .dae format, but when used in Augmented Faces on iOS - the animation does not work at all.
With what settings/animation features do you need to export models to .dae format in order for the animation to work?